# wordpress: The css is not loading , completely a white page

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, blogs

Is it for .htaccess file ?

There is no .htacces file in /var/www/wordpress.

Do i have to create a .htaccess file ?

What will be the contents of that .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that could be one of the reasons, [See here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F).

Comment: No, that was not a reason, i was installed over older database. So i removed older database and reinstalled it. It's done.